# How to add text behind file name in batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm having a problem where I want to to add date and time to my plugins folder, but for some reason it keeps saying that:

```
The filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The code is following (batch file is in the same folder as plugins folder is)

```
ren "plugins" "* %Date:/= % %TIME:~3,2%,%TIME:~0,2%*"
PAUSE
```

CMD window

```
C:\Users\Jakub Lapka\Desktop\BackUp>ren "plugins" "* 08.03.2020 51,16*"
The filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Is there any way how can I rename this so I can use this bacth file for several folders without hardcoding the file names?

Edit: I know that I have switched the time positions for HH and MM. I'll fix this later.

Comment: Give `for /d %f in (*) do ren %f "%f %Date:/= % %TIME:~3,2%,%TIME:~0,2%"` a shot once in the folder and see if that does the trick. If you are running from batch script and not command line then double the `%` character and use `for /d %%f in (*) do ren %%f "%%f %Date:/= % %TIME:~3,2%,%TIME:~0,2%"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are renaming the file in a ambiguous position. Two * wild cards are surrounding the date time variable, where to rename this can't be found. You must need an identifier. That can be a dot before the file extension. Also the file to rename dosent have extension. That can cause problem.

```
ren "plugins.ext" "*Date:/= % %TIME:~3,2%,%TIME:~0,2%.ext"
```